# How do I change a tag to blue?

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
<tr class="footer">
  <td colspan="6">
     <div class="quicklinks">           
        <span class="footer_link">          
            <span class="new"> 
               <a href="www.google.com">
                   <img title="mylink" src="" alt="mylink">My link</a>
            </span>
        </span>
     </div>
  </td>
```

and CSS:

```
a:link {
    color: red;
}

a:hover {
    color: green;
}

a:active {
    color: green;
}

a:visited {
    color: red;
}

a .footer_link  {

    color: blue;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5omhc44L/). How do I make my link blue via the .css? What's the order, no matter how many properties I write into it like a `.footer .footer_link` it doesn't change into blue. I also tried it with `!important` but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this: Target the anchor tag inside `footer_link` using descendant selector.

You were trying to select the `footer_link` inside anchor which doesn't exist and thus was using `a:link` style rules.

```css
a:link {
  color: red;
}
a:hover {
  color: green;
}
a:active {
  color: green;
}
a:visited {
  color: red;
}
.footer_link a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<tr class="footer">
  <td colspan="6">
    <div class="quicklinks">
      <span class="footer_link">          
            <span class="new"> 
               <a href="www.google.com">
                   <img title="mylink" src="" alt="mylink">My link</a>
            </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: No problem Paul. If you are trying to learn CSS selectors, I suggest you to look at this article: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 3):

You have written everything right.

There is just one corection required in your css code:

```
.footer_link a  {
    color: blue;
}
```

use anchor tag after .footer_link class.

I have updated your fiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5omhc44L/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's not changing to blue because you have `a:link {color: red}`

Simply remove this in your CSS.

```
a:link {
    color: red;
}
```

Or change to

```
a:link {
    color: blue;
}
```